# Mt4 recovering loss script

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, mt4, metatrader5

I'm trying to add the (if) condition to my EA for MT4, as this( if amount loss is higher than profit amount then complete martingale until losses are recovered, any one can give an Idea about the script? 
So if amount loss is higher than profit set recovering to true and multiply trade lot amount x3.

Comment: `mql5` / `mt5` tags, are they relevant here? write your code and we will try to help with it. technically nothing complicated, keep track of losses, sum them up and compute the lot accordingly

Comment: @DanielKniaz I'm using fxdreema to build my EA, I got a (if) condition but just don't know how to write the code I'm looking for, as you are a expert in MQL4, would you please advise me? please note that I can add custom MQL4 code but I just don't know how to write what I'm looking for in MQL4 scripts. hope to find help from you!